# How to prove that a axiom in a certain system is independent of the other ones?

Tags: logic, set-theory

As I'm learning *Zermelo–Fraenkel* set theory, a question arises: How do we know (or prove) a axiom in a axiomatic system is independent of the other ones? (that means we can not prove one from the rest)?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Construct two models, where all the other axioms hold. In model #1, the axiom of interest does hold, in model #2, it doesn't.

Comment: I would think to prove the axiom only using itself?

Comment: I would probably add a handful of other duplicates once I am on a proper keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it as an argument 'If all the other axioms hold, then this axiom holds', and produce a counterexample, i.e. find a scenario where all the other axioms hold but the one axiom does not.

Answer (score 2):

You can prove that a formula $\phi$ is independent of a set of formulas $\Gamma$, if you can obtain two structures $\mathcal{M,M'}$ such  that
$$
\mathcal{M}\models\Gamma\cup\phi \ \ \text{and} \ \mathcal{M'}\models\Gamma\cup\neg\phi
$$
Whit this and completeness theorem you can conclude that $\phi$ not follows of $\Gamma$.